# WebSphere-7 - Stopping our running application from WAS console shuts down WAS

Tags: websphere-7

We've deployed our EAR application in WAS-7. This EAR application uses asynchbeans, Work Manager. Purpose of this application is to have the work manager spawn some works, at the start of a servlet. These works are intended to run constantly, doing a polling and processing function(this app was originally standalone, the WAS enabling is done at our customer's insisting). The processing is happening satisfactorily, but, through WAS console, when we stop our app, it is taking the WAS also down with it. When we debug the servlet destroy of our app(where it is attempted to WorkManager.join(all workitems)), we see that our app has not managed to free all work manager resources used. Could it be because of this that, WAS is also shutting down when the app is stopped(We tried this app in WAS-6.1, where too the the behavior is same)? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

With the help of advice received from  developerWorks, issue was resolved, cause being System.exit in the app code. Also got to learn something from this useful link too - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21304559. Thank you.